# Blender VSE imported audio and video out of sync

Tags: blender, video-editing

I'm working on a short video with blender, and the first few strips I imported were fine. I then imported another strip(and tried re-recording it and importing that). For the new strip, the video is much shorter than the audio.

*In fact, I did a quick calculation, and the video is exactly 8 times shorter.(And faster)*

I have looked it up, and it says to match up the framerate in the settings, but then it messes up the sync of the other strips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was having the same issue. When you change the framerate, it seems to align everything with the same framerate but throw the others off sync. However, if you add a speed control effect to the video strip, turn on 'Stretch to input strip length' in that effect, and stretch the video strip to match the audio strip, they align. This person explains it better than I do: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-MZ4VXgEdzo